# Single table inheritance with enum type

Tags: hibernate

I have parent-child entity relationship as follows. Here I am going to map this inheritance for single table which is User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "USER_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,    length = 20)
@DiscriminatorValue("USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    .
    .
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "USER_TYPE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserType userType;
    .
    .

    //setters, getters

}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("MANAGER")
public class Manager extends User implements Serializable {
    // manager specific fields
}

User Types :

public enum UserType {
    MANAGER,
    ADMIN,
    ACCOUNTS_CLEARK
}
```

When I persist User object, the user type column get only USER, even I set user type in the persistance object (i.e. UserType.MANAGER). The actual hibernate insert statement as was follows;

```
Hibernate: insert into USER (ID, DOB, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME,     NICKNAME, USER_NAME, PASSWORD, USER_TYPE) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'USER')
```

and I am getting following exception when I tries to retrieve all records from user the table;

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value for enum class     com.test.domain.user.UserType: USER
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:105)
    at     org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2267)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1443)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1371)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:745)
    at     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at     org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at     org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.test.domain.user.UserType.USER
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:124)
    ... 47 more
```

I guess that each time I am going to save a user it picks @DiscriminatorValue which is USER and save in the user type field. Anyone come across and foud solution for this. Note that there is no type USER in the user type table.

Answer (score 1):

the property userType is readonly as specified in the annotation (insert=false, u8pdate=false) so it is never considered when inserting. the only value which is considered is the discriminator value specified for the class and that is set to USER for each User object persisted and MANAGER for each Manager object persisted. SO fix the mismatch between Discriminator value and UserType enum